# Why do I get an error when I try to play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So when I try to [play Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/play.jsp) it keeps giving me this error:

[image]

I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit and I have the latest version of Java installed. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1545 How can I fix this?

**@Brant:** I'm pretty sure I have 3D support. I just ran `dxdiag.exe`:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error generally means that your computer doesn't provide the 3D graphics support that Minecraft needs to run. If you're pretty sure you have the necessary 3D graphics hardware, you may need to update your video card's drivers.

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: "you may need to update your drivers" Have you tried that?

Comment: I updated the drivers and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at the OpenGL support for your graphics card. This is different from DirectX support.

Maybe you'll find some useful information at http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010479.htm

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817216/is-directx-on-java-possible

Unless Notch uses JNI, he's not using DirectX.  Considering that a lot of JNI code is not portable, and especially since DirectX doesn't exist on Linux and Mac without a lot of work, I'm fairly confident that your don't have to worry about it being your problem.  You should be looking more towards OpenGL (if Minecraft uses OpenGL) or your Java Runtime Environment.  Type `java -version` into a command window to show the version info.  They are much more likely to be the culprit.

Comment: Minecraft uses [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/), a Java graphics library that utilizes OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

DirectX != OpenGL.  Support for one on your graphics card and your drivers does not mean support for the other.  Even if your GFX card supports it, doesn't mean your drivers do and Dell are particularly bad at drivers. So if you are running the factory installed ones, or ones from the dell website, that will almost certainly be the issue.

Minecraft uses OpenGL, so dxdiag.exe is of no use here.

Your Graphics chip should support OpenGL, so head to the [Intel Graphics Driver update page](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/detect.htm) to check you are running the latest drivers for your card.

I have experienced OpenGL errors on a graphics card I knew supported it, and a driver update fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when running Minecraft in the browser from Firefox. I fixed it by switching to Internet Explorer (you can also download the executable). The other common resolution is to make sure your graphics drivers and Java are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same laptop and the exact same specs that you have now, and this is the only thing I use to play Minecraft. Here are some tips:

1. Minecraft does NOT run on Direct3d/DirectX.
2. You must have at least OpenGL 2.1 or higher.
3. Have the latest version of Java. (Probably Java 7 Update 67 or Java 8 Update 20 {Java 7 runs better and Java 8 is in beta. JAVA 7 RECOMMENDED}, as of October 3, 2014.)
4. Use Windows Update and select all graphics card updates and install them.
5. Your RAM must be more than 1 GB. (find it at Control Panel / System and Security / System.)

Tip No. 4 is the reason why i'm running Minecraft on my Dell Inspiron 1545 (which is almost impossible.). it's on the graphics driver, not the laptop.

[image: This is Minecraft Multiplayer on a Dell Inspiron 1545]